# What is the complexity class of counting Yes/No instances of an NP problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete

Let's say that I have an NP-complete problem such as the Clique Problem. Let's also assume that I have a finte set of graphs. What is the complexity of counting Yes/No instances?

More specifically let's define a new decision problem that returns Yes on a finite set of graphs if the number of Yes instances is $\geq$ a constant $k$ and the number of No instances is $\leq$ a constant $l$ Equivalently $l' \leq \operatorname{count}(Yes) \leq k$. In what complexity class does this problem belong? I know it can be solved in polynomial time with an NP oracle but is it hard in this class or is there a lower bound?

In a more general setting if I need the set of graphs to satisfy a condition $c(\operatorname{count}(Yes), \operatorname{count}(No)) \leq k$, where $c$ is an arbitrary function, does the problem become harder?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to specify the problem more carefully.  What are the inputs to the algorithm?  Are $l,k$ inputs?  Are they fixed numbers like 3,5 and you're allowed to choose a different algorithm for every choice of $l,k$?  Something else?  It might help to describe the context in which you encountered this or the motivation for asking.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [$\#\mathsf{P}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP), a set of counting problems.

See [this paper](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Eaf1p/Teaching/MCC17/Papers/enumerate.pdf) for some examples of $\#\mathsf{P}$-complete problems.

Comment: I think $\# P$ might be harder since I don't care about the exact number of Yes instances, only bounds on it. E.g. if I only have a bound on Yes instances I can verify in polynomial time that there are at least that many.

Comment: If you can count the exact number, you can deduce bounds. Conversely, if you can know bounds, you can find the exact number using dichotomic search. So I think those class are equals.